# what is the use of -U option in ping command?

Tags: linux, ping

I was learning ping command and their options.

In ping -U option is used for full user to user latency.

There is no difference for ping and ping -U option in output.

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.199.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=1 ttl=57 time=49.9 ms
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=2 ttl=57 time=44.6 ms
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=3 ttl=57 time=43.6 ms
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=4 ttl=57 time=45.6 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 43.641/45.990/49.991/2.422 ms

$ ping -U google.com
PING google.com (216.58.199.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=1 ttl=57 time=54.9 ms
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=3 ttl=57 time=46.0 ms
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=4 ttl=57 time=42.8 ms
64 bytes from bom05s08-in-f14.1e100.net (216.58.199.174): icmp_req=5 ttl=57 time=42.2 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 4 received, 33% packet loss, time 5013ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 42.267/46.544/54.984/5.091 ms
```

Can anyone please explain me what is the difference between these two commands and what is the use of -U option in ping command.

Comment: Yes, they are different, and in exactly the way described in the man page.

Comment: But in output there is no difference. How can I feel the difference in the output ?

Comment: @suresh As the man page describes, the time measurement is done differently.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist how the time is measured for the -U option ?

Answer (score 0):

`man ping`

```
   -U     Print  full  user-to-user  latency (the old behaviour). Normally
          ping prints network round trip time, which can be different f.e.
          due to DNS failures.
```

Comment: What is meant by full user to user latency and when the time will be different ?

Comment: So what is the ***difference***?